# automate deployment on EC2 using CodeDeploy and Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: git, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a project written in **Django (Python Framework)** and repository in **Bitbucket**

I have to setup a bitbucket pipeline with the following actions:

1. Deploy in Staging server and commits are made to **staging** branch
2. Deploy to Production server when a release is a draft from the master branch only.

I'm not sure where release can be draft in Bitbucket like Github.

I have the following **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** file

```
image: python:3.7

pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          deployment: staging
          script: 
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install -y zip # required for packaging up the application
            - pip install boto3==1.3.0 # required for codedeploy_deploy.py
            - zip -r /tmp/artifact.zip * # package up the application for deployment
            - python codedeploy_deploy.py # run the deployment script
```

Now, In the Django application, I'm using `.env` to serve credentials and settings. For a different environment, say development, staging, and production, I have different environment files for each

```
development.env
staging.env
production.env
```

I need to rename/copy the respective file to `.env` depending on the deployment type.

**How can I set up this in bitbucket pipeline to carry out this step?**

**appspec.yml** contents are:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/project/
permissions:
  - object: /var/www/html
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/clean_instance.sh
      timeout: 6000
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_os_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 6000
      runas: root
    - location: scripts/install_python_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 6000
      runas: ubuntu
    - location: scripts/setup_environment.sh
      timeout: 6000
      runas: ubuntu
    - location: scripts/migrate.sh
      timeout: 6000
      runas: ubuntu
    - location: scripts/ngnix.sh
      timeout: 6000
      runas: ubuntu
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_application.sh
      timeout: 6000
      runas: ubuntu
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_application.sh
      timeout: 6000
      runas: ubuntu
```

**Can I have multiple appspec.yml files depending on the deployment type?**

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple directories under application version name might be a good solution.

```
1.0.0->
      appspec.yml
      files/
      scripts/
```

Comment: How will `codedeploy_deploy` change the directory to use specific `appsec.yml`?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to whether you can use different appspec.yml files?